# Does Donkey even have a real name at all?

Tags: shrek

Does Donkey introduce himself as "Donkey", or does Shrek start calling him that because he is a donkey and everyone just rolls with it? Does Donkey even have a real name at all?

Answer (score 15):

Donkey's name is Donkey. He introduces himself as such.

> **Donkey:** *All right, that's what I like to hear, man. **Shrek and Donkey**, two stalwart friends, off on a whirlwind big-city adventure. I love it!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Shrek - Movie Transcript](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/s/shrek-script-transcript-mike-myers.html)</sup></sub>

And in the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2291617.Shrek_Novel), we have proof-positive that he's called Donkey *by his owner*.

> There were two villagers with elves, an old man with a wooden puppet
> of a boy, **an old woman with a donkey she called Donkey**, a boy with a
> glowing fairy in a cage, and a burly peasant with three little pigs
> under his arms.
>
> <sub><sup>[Shrek: A Novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2291617.Shrek_Novel)</sup></sub>

Note that Shrek only refers to him as "*little donkey*" ([The script](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/%7Eina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Shrek.pdf) shows this is without caps) until they get to the bridge.

[image]

and this is how Donkey is introduced in the script

[image]